# frequency distribution plot of data from CSV file in R

Tags: r, csv, plot

I am a novice in R and I have been trying to work out a solution to my issue

I have read in data from a csv file, which contains certain values in a column. The next column has the frequency of each value row-wise.

e.g -

```
stored as csvdata<- read.csv(file="filename.csv",head=FALSE,sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

v1  v2
5   2
10  3
15  1
20  3
25  4
30  2
```

and I want to output a chart type like this

[image]

I tried to do

```
csvdata(filename)
```

and

```
plot(csvdata[,V1],csvdata[,V2])
```

so far no luck.

I not sure how to make a plot like this and would appreciate any help.

Comment: You want a barplot: `?barplot`.

Comment: Try `barplot(csvdata[,"v2"], names=csvdata[,"v1"])`

Comment: it says Error in csvdata[, "v2"] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only the base R could do the job.

```
barplot(height = csvdata$v2,names.arg = csvdata$v1,col='lightblue',main='Chart Title')
legend('topleft',legend='Series 1',fill='lightblue')
```

The code is self-explaining. Since I don't have enough reputation to post the resulted image, here is the [graph](http://postimg.org/image/3laco5n85) generated by the two-line code above.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to open up the `ggplot2` can o' worms, you could start with something like this and then modify to your heart's content:

```
library(ggplot2)
DF <- data.frame(v1=c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30), v2=c(2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2))

p <- ggplot(DF) + geom_bar(aes(x=v1, y=v2),stat="identity")
p <- p + theme_classic()
p <- p + labs(title='Chart Title', x='series 1', y='')
p
```

Gives you:

[image]

Comment: I like your solution ! though I was looking for something using Base R. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Your welcome, glad you got a solution. You could mention if you want Base R in the question as well.